# How to measure test coverage in Go

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, code-coverage

Has anyone succeeded in generating code coverage for Go unit tests? I can't find a tool for that on the web.

Comment: For VSCode users: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/features.md#code-coverage

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Note that [Go 1.2 (Q4 2013, rc1 is available)](http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list?can=2) will now display **[test coverage results](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.2#cover)**:

> One major new feature of `go test` is that **it can now compute and, with help from a new, separately installed "`go tool cover`" program, display test coverage results**.
>
> The `cover` tool is part of the [`go.tools` subrepository](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/checkout?repo=tools). It can be installed by running
>
> ```
> $ go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover
> ```
>
> The cover tool does two things.
>
> - First, when "`go test`" is given the `-cover` flag, it is run automatically to rewrite the source for the package and insert instrumentation statements. The test is then compiled and run as usual, and basic coverage statistics are reported:
>
>   $ go test -coverprofile fmtcoverage.html fmt
>   ok    fmt 0.060s  coverage: 91.4% of statements
>   $
> - Second, for more detailed reports, different flags to "go test" can create a coverage profile file, which the cover program, invoked with "`go tool cover`", can then analyze.

[Frank Shearar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10259/frank-shearar) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516662/how-to-measure-test-coverage-in-go/18911602#comment28995405_18911602):

> The latest versions of Go (2013/09/19) use:
>
> ```
> go test -coverprofile <filename> <package name>
> ```
>
> Details on how to generate and analyze coverage statistics can be found by running the commands
>
> ```
> $ go help testflag
> $ go tool cover -help
> ```

---

[Ivan Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816872/ivan-black) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516662/how-to-measure-test-coverage-in-go/18911602#comment46046413_18911602):

> `go test -coverprofile cover.out` and then
> `go tool cover -html=cover.out` opens `cover.out` in your default browser
>
> I don't even want to wait for the browser to open, so I defined this alias:
>
> ```
> alias gc=grep -v -e " 1$" cover.out
> ```
>
> That I just type `gc`, and have a list of all the lines *not* yet covered (here: with a `coverage.out` line *not* ending with " `1`").

---

Update 2022, possibly for Go 1.19

> ### [proposal: extend Go's code coverage testing to include applications](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51430)

> While the existing "`go test`" based coverage workflow will continue to be supported, the proposal is to add coverage as a new build mode for "`go build`".
>
> In the same way that users can build a race-detector instrumented executable using "`go build -race`", it will be possible to build a coverage-instrumented executable using "`go build -cover`".
>
> Merging coverage profiles produced in different GOOS/GOARCH environments will be supported.

---

Update March 2023, [Go 1.20](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#cover): "[**Code coverage for Go integration tests**](https://go.dev/blog/integration-test-coverage)" shows that you can now build coverage-instrumented programs using “go build -cover”, then feed these instrumented binaries into an integration test to extend the scope of coverage testing.

Comment: Note that the latest versions of Go (2013/09/19) use `go test -coverprofile <filename> <package name>`

Comment: @FrankShearar Ok. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `go test -coverprofile cover.out` and then `go tool cover -html=cover.out -o cover.html` open `cover.html` in browser

Comment: @IvanBlack good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility. I also added an alias I use to quickly see non-covered lines.

Comment: @VonC `go tool cover -html=cover.out` will automatically opens a browser, but it doesn't work for my system. I prefer to keep a browser open and refresh the page if necessary.

Comment: @IvanBlack true. I guess I am more a command-line person myself ;)

Comment: `go tool cover` has moved to new URL, so please use command `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover` instead.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have multiple packages in your project, generating a coverage profile is not quite so easy. If you run something like `go test ./... -coverprofile=cover.out` you get the following error: `cannot use test profile flag with multiple packages`. There's still an [open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6909) to add support for this.

Comment: @SamJones For that, you have https://github.com/mattn/goveralls and https://github.com/haya14busa/goverage (mentioned in https://medium.com/@haya14busa/golang-tips-you-might-not-know-1c90e6921a3#abb6)

Answer (score 72):

In addition to the good answers above, I find these three lines to be the simplest way to get it (which includes all packages):

```
go test -v -coverprofile cover.out ./YOUR_CODE_FOLDER/...
go tool cover -html cover.out -o cover.html
open cover.html
```

Note that in the HTML file you will find a dropdown button that will direct you to all files.

See `go tool cover -help` for additional options.

Comment: I was getting errors as "too many arguments. For usage information, run "go tool cover -help"". 
That is solved by removing "=" after -html tag
go tool cover -html cover.out -o cover.html

Comment: `open cover.html` works fine but it generates unwanted listener logs in the same terminal in ubuntu as follows ```bash Gtk-Message: 00:03:41.903: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 00:03:41.904: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"```

Comment: Great help! you might want to mention the `...` is used for recursively search for inner folders.

Answer (score 70):

Go comes with awesome tool for testing and coverage. Although all Go tools are well documented `go tool cover -help` I would suggest reading [The cover story article on the official Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/cover). It has plenty of examples and I strongly recommend it!

I have this function in my ~/.bash_profile. (you can just paste it in the terminal to give it a try).

```
cover () { 
    t="/tmp/go-cover.$$.tmp"
    go test -coverprofile=$t $@ && go tool cover -html=$t && unlink $t
}
```

Then just `cd` into a go project/package folder and type `cover`.
This opens a visual tool in browser which shows you the tested and untested code for each file in the current package. Very useful command! I strongly recommend it for finding what is not 100% tested yet! The shown results are per file. From a drop down in top-left you can see results for all files.

With this command you can also check the coverage of any package for example:

`cover fmt`

The output in terminal from this command would be:

```
ok      fmt 0.031s  coverage: 91.9% of statements
```

In addition to that in your browser you will see this tool showing in red all lines of code which are not covered with tests:

[image]

It is also possible to just save the html coverage file instead of opening it in a browser. This is very useful in cases when your tests + coverage is run by CI tool like Jenkins. That way you can serve the coverage files from a central server and the whole team will be able to see the coverage results for each build.

Comment: Snippet copied from here https://coderwall.com/p/rh-v5a/get-coverage-of-golang-test

Comment: Interesting, I will test it. +1

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for sharing. Ended up moving into a test script as I wanted to test a main package in my program. Cheers

Comment: If you want the per file percentage as a list you can use `cat cover.out.html | grep '<option value="file' | sed -E 's/.*>(.*) \((.*)%\)<.*/\2 \1/' | sort -rn`

Answer (score 36):

Simply run

```
go test -cover
```

or

```
go test -cover ./...
```

or

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./... ;    go tool cover -func=coverage.out
```

or to check the source code

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./... ;    go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Comment: doesn't work on Windows11

Comment: @RezaTaba it doesn't seem true, these commands are platform independent, what exactly is your problem? (why do you say it doesn't work?)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was at the time. However I found a better solution through the VSCode's Command Pallete which is already integrated. Provided my solution here.

Answer (score 17):

> I can't find a tool for that on the web.

Actually... there is now (2022) such a tool on the web, from [Nikolay Dubina](https://github.com/nikolaydubina)'s project [`go-cover-treemap-web`](https://github.com/nikolaydubina/go-cover-treemap-web):

https://go-cover-treemap.io/

Nothing it uploaded (the processing remains local), but by dragging/dropping your coverprofile, the Web UI (using Go WASM) will run [`go-cover-treemap`](https://github.com/nikolaydubina/go-cover-treemap) and display:

[image: https://github.com/nikolaydubina/go-cover-treemap/raw/main/docs/hugo.svg]
<sup>(gocovergage for https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo)</sup>

Answer (score 17):

Already built-in in VSCode

1. **Ctrl+Shift+P** to Open Command Palette
2. **Go: Toggle Test Coverage ...**

The **Green** part is tested and **Red** is not

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Was wondering why I couldn't find a good custom solution for viewing test coverage in VS Code, as apparently it already existed natively.

Comment: For some reason the commands mentioned in answer above doesn't work for me. I keep getting "No required module provides package .out; to add it: go get .out". But this worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Coverage Report:

a) Run all the tests and enable coverage --> `go test ./... -coverprofile coverage.out`

b) Get coverage for individual functions as well as overall coverage → `go tool cover -func coverage.out`

c) See the lines covered and the ones not covered by your tests → `go tool cover -html=coverage.out -o coverage.html`. Open the `coverage.html` file hereby generated in the browser and analyze the detailed coverage info.

Answer (score 5):

It's right [here](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/#hg/src/cmd/cov), some docs [here](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/cov/doc.go).

```
$ go tool
6a
6c
6g
6l
addr2line
api
cgo
cov
dist
ebnflint
fix
gotype
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
prof
vet
yacc
$ go tool cov -h
usage: cov [-lsv] [-g substring] [-m minlines] [6.out args...]
-g specifies pattern of interesting functions or files
go tool cov: exit status 1
$
```

I haven't used it, this is all I know.

Comment: do you have to install it manually? in my local go installation (go version go1) it is not there.

Comment: I believe it gets build by ./all.bash. I cannot verify ATM, I'm not at release as I have a CL pending, but the cov binary time stamp I see in `~/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64` matches my last Go build of yesterday.

Comment: Yes, run ./all.bash and you will have it. Thanks for the help, jnml!

Comment: I have some problems running it on my x86 machine. I tried changing main.c as mentioned in this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/golang-dev/browse_thread/thread/59c18314b18cbf9e
But it generates a runtime error in another location. I will try it on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you like to see the uncovered lines by function directly in a terminal I rewrote the cover tool for this purpose. It's available at https://github.com/gregoryv/uncover.

**Usage**

```
go get -u github.com/gregoryv/uncover/...
go test -coverprofile /tmp/c.out
uncover /tmp/c.out
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **VSCode** this functionality is supported out the box ( *But disabled by default* )

Just turn on test on save + coverage reporting

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/On-Save-features

It will even show in your editor which lines are not covered which is super handy.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find test coverage in `Windows`, just go to the desired folder in `command prompt` and type the following command:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out && go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

This is perfectly easy and works reliably.

Comment: I get this error >> no required module provides package .out; to add it:
        go get .out

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way is to use the coverage tool that comes with built-in go :

> **$ go test -coverprofile cp.out**
>    // Emits the coverage in one liner percentage wise

After you execute the above command, if you wish to visually see the code coverage (like covered statements and missed etc)

> **$ go tool cover -html=cp.out**

Note : You need to execute the above commands in the folder where you wish to see coverage

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
go test -v -cover ./...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[gaia-docker/base-go-build](https://github.com/gaia-docker/base-go-build)** Docker Image.

This is a Docker image that contains all you need in order to build and test coverage.
Running test coverage inside a Docker container creates *.cover* folder with test coverage results of your project.

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":$PROJECT_PATH -w $PROJECT_PATH $BUILDER_IMAGE_NAME /go/script/coverage.sh
```

The [test coverage script](https://github.com/gaia-docker/base-go-build/blob/master/script/coverage.sh) running on all projects' folders and generates, inside *.cover* folder junit and coverage reports for each folder, and a combine coverage report of all projects' tests.

Codecov also suggests a script that collect coverage results: [multiple files](https://github.com/codecov/example-go#caveat-multiple-files)

Answer (score -1):

> Test Coverage for Golang

`go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
go get -u gopkg.in/matm/v1/gocov-html`

Check It is Installed Correctly And you have access from your Terminal

> Run the Test Case

If you run the test case it will Reder the .json File Based on the file you will get the Code Coverage Report in .html file

`gocov test >your_Coverage_report.json`

Once Your Test case is done Generate a Report in .html File  using .json

`gocov-html your_Coverage_report.json >your_Coverage_report.html`

Reference

[GoTest Coverage Tool for go lang](https://github.com/axw/gocov)

[Go Test Report Tool](https://github.com/matm/gocov-html)

> Alternate Method

**Go Native Test coverage**

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Answer (score -2):

A better test coverage reporter than `go tool cover`:

https://github.com/JacksonTian/gocov

[image]